# Quiz Application showing Negative Score

Tags: php, session

I've a fb quiz application which is working fine if we check correct question and then go for next question but its showing negative score when i change options multiple times

I'm calling ajax onchange on selecting option to update score page and storing score in session

in this codes it works fine if we select correct answer and then wrong so it decrease but when selecting wrong and then we got negative score because of

```
$_SESSION['score']--;
```

How to solve this problem ???

```
    // check if this option is correct for current question
    $check_anwer_query = mysql_query("select * from tbl_option where ques_id=$ques_id and opt_id=$opt_id") or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($check_anwer_query))
    {
        $rs = mysql_fetch_array($check_anwer_query);

        if($rs['opt_value']==1) 
        {
            $_SESSION['score']++;
            //$_SESSION[$ques_id]='1';
        }
        else if($_SESSION['lastq']==$ques_id) // check if option is changed, 
        {   

            $_SESSION['score']--;

        }
        if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
        {
            mysql_query("delete from tmp_quiz where ques_id=$ques_id and uid='".$_SESSION['user']."'") or die(mysql_error());
            if($rs['opt_value']==1) 
            {   
                mysql_query("insert into tmp_quiz(ques_id,opt_id,uid,is_correct) values($ques_id,$opt_id,'".$_SESSION['user']."',1)") or die(mysql_error());    
            }
            else
            {
                mysql_query("insert into tmp_quiz(ques_id,opt_id,uid,is_correct) values($ques_id,$opt_id,'".$_SESSION['user']."',0)") or die(mysql_error());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            mysql_query("delete from tmp_quiz where ques_id=$ques_id and tmp_id='".$_SESSION['tmp_id']."'") or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_query("insert into tmp_quiz(ques_id,opt_id,tmp_id) values($ques_id,$opt_id,'".$_SESSION['tmp_id']."')") or die(mysql_error());
        }

    }   

    $_SESSION['lastq'] = $ques_id; // assign current question as last question answred
?>
```

Comment: have you tried to pin down exactly where you're going down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Logic for Score Start

        $rs = mysql_fetch_array($check_anwer_query);

        if($rs['opt_value']==1) 
        {
            $_SESSION['score']++;
            $_SESSION["test_".$ques_id]='1'; // if Answer is Correct Set Session
        }
        elseif($_SESSION['lastq']==$ques_id) // check if option is changed
        {   
            if(isset($_SESSION["test_".$ques_id])) { // if Last Ansewer is same as current question and last answer is yes then substract score
            $_SESSION['score']--;
            unset($_SESSION["test_".$ques_id]); }   // Unset That Session
        }
        elseif(isset($_SESSION['test_'.$_SESSION['lastq']])) // If Last Question Session is still exists Then Unset That Question Session
        { 
            unset($_SESSION['test_'.$_SESSION['lastq']]);
        }

        //Logic for Score End
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not do relative calculations, since that requires you to be certain that the state shared between the UI and your session is 100% in sync and that no user actions arrive out of order (which I guess is where your problem is).

Instead, save all chosen answers in the session. When wanting to display the user's score, run through all chosen answers and calculate a number based on that. Do this *every time* you want to display the user's score, so the score is always up to date and accurate.